# Rails including JavaScript twice in development?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline

I have a file application.js which uses Sprockets to require other files.

I include this JS with     <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>

In development, however, it is including the included files individually, and also the /assets/application.js file:

```
<script src="/assets/json2.min.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/handlebars-v1.3.0.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/main/first.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/main/constants.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/main/main.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/application.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

How can I get it to not include the /assets/application.js file in development?  I need the public folder for other things, like images, so I don't want to delete the folder entirely.

Answer (score 0):

Check your application.js file. It probably contains:

```
//= require_tree .
```

That's why all your files in /assets/js folder are included